# Editing Vim indent files

Tags: vim, indentation

I have a **Vim indent file**.
It is not indenting some words like **module**.
I want to add indent for some more words.
Where should I add these words???

Comment: can you please explain what is a `vim indent file`?

Comment: It is asked to place in the indent folder...
please refer 
http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=4743

Answer (score 0):

Vim *indent plugins* (the scripts in `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/*.vim`) either contain custom settings for Vim's built-in indent-related options (like `'cindent'`, `'cinoptions'`), or (in the majority) a custom Vimscript program that is installed into the `'indentexpr'` option.

What such program does (and how it can be configured / extended) is flexible and up to the program's author. Therefore, **no general recipe can be given**.

1. Check the list of built-in filetypes at `:help indent-expression`. If your filetype is listed there, maybe there's a configuration for your particular problem.
2. Else, study the source code of the particular indent script. Maybe you can extend it to match your needs. (If this is generally useful, then send a patch to the plugin's author (listed at the top of the script).)